# java.net.URI - : Illegal character in fragment at index XXX - due to character "#"

Tags: java, url

The source code is as follows: (a-zA-Z all replaced with x)

```
String url = "xxxxx://xx730xxxxxxx005.xxxx.xxx:8443/xxx/xxxxxxxxx.xxxx#xxxxxx=xxxxxxx2&&xxxxxxxxx=1388782204000&&xxxxxxx=1388785804000&&xxxxx=xxxxxxxxxxx='xxx-xx730xxxxx10'%20xxx%20xxxxxxxx='__xxx__xxx_xxx_xxxxxxx_xxxx_xxxxxxxxx_#2_xxx-xx__xxx_xxx_xxxxxxx_______xxxx'"

System.out.println(url2.charAt(215)); -> result #
URI.create(url2); // illegal character exception
```

I don't understand why would I get illegal character in fragment at index 215 for "#" when it is a valid URL character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [URI specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-24) states

> The fragment identifier component of a URI allows indirect
> identification of a secondary resource by reference to a primary
> resource and additional identifying information. [...]  **A fragment
> identifier component is indicated by the presence of a number sign
> ("#") character and terminated by the end of the URI.**

The format is

```
fragment    = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
```

where `pchar` is

```
pchar       = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
```

where `unreserved`, `pct-encoded` and `sub-delims` are

```
unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
pct-encoded = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
             / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

In other words, `#` is not a valid character after the first `#` which indicates the start of the fragment. It needs to be encoded. Use `%23`.

Comment: is there an API to "escape" all the invalid characters?

Comment: @user Spring's `UriComponentsBuilder` class (in `spring-web` library) will do it for you.

Comment: @user4127 None that I know of. The `URI.create(String)` method states `IllegalArgumentException - If the given string violates RFC 2396`. So the `String` you pass must be a valid URI.

Comment: but the link provided in the answer is for 3986

Comment: @user4127 [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier) seems to say that 3986 is the most up to date spec. Regardless, if you look at both, they have the same acceptable characters for the `fragment` part of the URI. The Javadoc just wasn't updated I guess.

Comment: @user4127 workaround java only: split at first '#', then java.net.URLEncoder.encode(part2), then recompose the url with escaped part, then parse. Depending on the meaning of the original URI you may have to first URLDecoder.decode(part2,"UTF-8") before encoding it. Note that in escaped form new URI has '+' where was '%20'.